# How can I clone a private repo in ECS docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Hi I'm new to AWS ECS and I'm trying to deploy a docker cluster. I have a private github repo that I want to download to my working directory when my docker container starts, or possibly have it on some ebs volume preloaded that is then mounted by my ECS container instance. What is the best approach to doing this, I've been very overwhelmed by the aws documentation and haven't seen anything that talks about git cloning with credentials or ebs preloaded with source code.

Comment: You'll probably want to take a look at AWS CodeDeploy.

Comment: Why are you mounting code from outside your container? Usually, you would build the image to container your code and dependencies so that you don't need to mount anything from the outside (other than configuration or secrets). Anyways, I have an example of using Docker and CodeDeploy together at https://github.com/andyshinn/docker-codedeploy-example that may help. CodeDeploy would help you pull other bits from S3 or git at build or runtime. However, you lose out on some of the scheduling and scaling properties of ECS.

Comment: I gave up and just built ami instances that act like my docker containers. I just pull in fresh code on ec2 instance restart via rc.local. There's too much magic going on with this code deploy that I don't understand.

Comment: This is an old question, but the way I've learn is to build once and run everywhere. I was not aware of this as a best practice since I saw docker as a good way to normalize environments between dev and prod. Also I saw docker as being configurable on startup as a best practice. Now it's obvious docker was built with the immutable state mindset.